# Set Variable to Query Dynamically Through Beeline

Tags: hive, beeline

I need to use the output of a hive query as a variable in another hive query through beeline. So something like

`select * from 123 where some_variable='select abc from xyz';`

However hive doesn't support sub-queries in where clauses so I instead would do it through a shell command. This is easy enough using the standard hive cli, i would just do something like this:

`my_shell_var=$(hive -S -e "select abc from xyz;")`

Then I would run:

`hive -e "select * from 123 where some_variable=$my_shell_var;"`

However beeline output includes borders so my_shell_var is surrounded as such

`+------+ some output +------+`

So I can't insert this back into the next query because the extra character change my string. Is there a way to either remove borders from beeline output or is there an alternative method to achieve what I'm trying to do altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use in clause?

select * from 123 where some_variable in (select abc from xyz)

Comment: Hive doesn't support sub-queries in where clause

Comment: it does from hive 0.13 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

Comment: Ah interesting, it only supports IN, NOT IN, EXISTS and NOT EXISTS I had used '=' and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, you can put:

`--showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2`

in your beeline cli command ie.

`my_shell_var=$(beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "your query")`

Then use shell to put that variable into your next query:

`beeline -e "select * from 123 where some_variable=$my_shell_var;"`

The output will not have any headers (--showHeader=false) or borders (--outputformat=tsv2).